# I used = in entity query condition, but the actual SQL uses LIKE

Tags: 9

The code is

```
$entity_query->condition("field_gov.entity.field_name", $time, '=');
```

The actual sql is

```
WHERE "paragraph__field_name"."field_name_value" LIKE 'ss' ESCAPE '\\'
```

I want the actual sql also use =. How can I do?

Comment: If it only happens on paragraph fields it could be a bug in paragraph module

Comment: See line 115 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Query/Sql/Condition.php. The field type for your `field_name_value` is configured so that queries for it are not considered case sensitive, which Drupal realises using `LIKE` instead of `=`. Is it causing you an actual problem that you need to fix?

Comment: It looks like an entity reference problem，Is there a solution？